# Cairo dock menus doesn't work

Tags: cairo-dock

I'm trying to use **gnome-shell** with cairo dock in 12.04, but there is one problem, I want to have some kind of menu in cairo dock.

The thing is, non of the menus I tried work in cairo dock. I tried mintmenu, gnomenu, cardapio, all of them show up in cairo dock, but then I press them, nothing happens. It just killing me.

Answer (score 0):

yes for me the same problem. I've workarounded the problem for Cardapio adding a custom launcher on Cairo associating the command "cardapio show-near-mouse". No solution yet for GnoMenu. Some help?